# Access composer.json /composer.phar

Tags: php, json, composer-php, phar

I have installed composer.phar in the following directory:

```
/public_html/composer
```

I have already added on package to the composer.json as below:

```
{
    "require": {
        "stripe/stripe-php": "2.*"
    }
}
```

That was some time ago. I would now like to install another package, using composer. However, I cannot access it. I am trying to do the following in SSH/Terminal:

```
root@host [~]# composer.phar
-bash: composer.phar: command not found
```

Then I try to:

```
root@host [~]# cd public_html
root@host [~/public_html]# cd composer
-bash: cd: composer: No such file or directory
root@host [~/public_html]#
```

What am I doing wrong? In FTP I can see the composer is located in the `/public_html/` folder, but I can't acccess it?

**EDIT:**

```
ls -l composer
```

gives me:

```
/bin/ls: Can't access composer: No such file or directory
```

Using `ls -a` I get:

```
./             .bwusage.sqlite  error_log       perl5/        .spamassassin/
../            .composer/       .forward        php.ini.new   .ssh/
.accesshash    .cpanel/         .gnupg/         php.ini.orig  support/
.bash_history  cpanel3-skel/    .HttpRequest/   .pki/         .tcshrc
.bash_logout   .cpanm/          .lesshst        public_ftp/   tmp/
.bash_profile  .cpobjcache/     .MirrorSearch/  public_html/  .trustwavereqs
.bashrc        .cshrc           .my.cnf         .rnd          .viminfo
```

Comment: Uhm... `cd public_html && ./composer`...!? `composer` is *the executable*, not a directory, no?

Comment: Have you tried `php composer.phar`?

Comment: /composer is just the directory I have added the composer.phar etc. files to.

Comment: `cd public_html && ./composer.phar` in this case, the executable is the phar file, it can be added as an alias tho.

Comment: @orestiss "php composer.phar" gives the same result as "composer.phar"

Comment: @Pred That command gives me "No such file or directory"; though I am navigated to the "public_html" folder

Comment: What does `ls -l composer` or generally `ls -a` say? If you can see it, it should be there, though `cd` seems to disagree.

Comment: note that `/public_html` is different from `~/public_html` ...

Comment: @deceze I updated my original question to include both commands.

Comment: when you are logged in as root the home directory for the root user is different than the root directory `/`

Comment: Well, `composer` is clearly not in the directories you're doing `ls` in. Have you tried the same in `public_html`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem I believe is that `/public_html/composer` is under the root `/` and there is also a `public_html` under `/root` (home directory for root user) directory

use `pwd` to check where you are at the moment and use `ls /public_html/composer` to see if `composer.phar` is in this directory.

You can run: `php /public_hmtl/composer/composer.phar`.

In order to be able to run it as `composer` you must `mv` the `composer.phar` to a directory that is included in your PATH variable.

For example:

`mv /public_html/composer/composer.phar /usr/bin/composer`

Answer (score 0):

So your structure is: `public_html/composer/composer.phar`

If so, then either navigate into the composer folder (`cd public_html/composer`), then issue the `./composer.phar` or `php ./composer.phar` command.

You can excute it using relative/absolute paths (`./public_html/composer/composer.phar` or `/srv/www/mysite/whatever/public_html/composer/composer.phar`)

Please note, that you have to execute composer from the folder where your `composer.json` file is located.

In all cases you have to have access to the folder and the file itself.